# Sort absolute values of array in less than O(n^2) JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Given a sorted array of both positive and negative numbers (Example:-9, -7, -4, -0.9, 1, 2, 3, 8) i need to output the elements in the array in sorted order of their absolute values in less than O(N^2) without using any inbuilt function.

Does anyone know any acceptable solution for this simple problem?
I was thinking of modifying the quicksort algorithm to make it check the abs values for elements.

Comment: `I was thinking of modifying the quicksort algorithm to make it check the abs values for elements.` -- Sounds good to me.

Comment: Also start at whatever index is 0 and move outwards in both directions where you only move a pointer if its abs value is less than that of the other pointer (a pos and neg pointer)

Comment: Since this is Java, a `Comparator` might work.

Comment: Problem is i can't use any inbuilt function.

Comment: Standard sorting algorithms work with any well-defined comparison method.  Implement a standard sorting algorithm in your own code with your own well-defined comparison method.

Comment: This is a simple merge of two arrays.  It can be done in O(N) time, more or less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would binary search for 0, conceptually split the list into 2 parts, and merge the two lists (the negative value one as the positive value of itself) into a single new one by walking the negative in reverse and the positive forward.

O(log n) for binary search, O(n) for the merge of 2 sorted lists.

Comment: No need for the O(log N) search.  Start from both ends and work towards the middle.

Comment: True hot licks. A simpler method would be to remove items from the bottom and merge them into the top while walking down.

Comment: Well, if you're working with real arrays and not something theoretical it would be better to merge into a 3rd array, since otherwise you'd have to shove stuff down (or at least swap the positive values into the vacated negative slots).  An in-place algorithm would be apt to be inefficient.

Comment: This is the idea that I used in my implementation, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

- Pick any 2-way comparison sorting algorithm of your pleasure with runtime bounds less than O(N^2).  Quicksort is a valid choice.
- When doing comparisons (which will show up in the 2-way comparison sorting algorithm), instead of comparing the values `a` and `b` compare `abs(a)` and `abs(b)`.  Just make sure that you don't replace `a` and `b` with `abs(a)` and `abs(b)`, just use the latter two when doing comparasons

Comment: Related to this answer is that this sounds an awful lot like a homework problem.  If this is a homework problem, your choice of sorting algorithms should be based on what gets you a good grade.  If this is not a homework problem, I'd like to know why the built-in sorts are not acceptable for this task.  Generally speaking, if one asks questions phrased like this, one doesn't usually make sorting algorithms that outperform those made by Computer Scientists who make a living developing fast sorts.

Comment: _"Quicksort is a valid choice."_ No, quicksort is O(N^2) in the worst case. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

Answer (score 0):

Just have two pointers at the end of the arrays then compare the absolute value with the end.

```
start == array[0]
end == array.length

while start != end

  if abs(start) => end
    put start in front of end
    start++
    end--
  else
    end--
```

I might be missing some pieces but that's the idea.

`0(n) solution.`